# JavaFX: How to know which part of an Observable has been modified?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Say I have an observable class with some properties:

```
public class ObservableClass implements Observable {
  private Property1 property1;
  private Property2 property2;
  private Property3 property3;

  (... getters and setters who invalidate the object)
}
```

If I have a `view` class who reacts on changes to the model:

```
public class View implements InvalidationListener{
  @Override
    public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
      // What should go here?
    }
}
```

How can I determine which property of the model has changed? I don't want to re-compute the whole view for every little change to the model, so how can I specify separate listeners for each property?

Comment: If property is updated by (and only by) a `getter` you can use if to flag a change to it. If can function as a property change listener.

Comment: The usual approach is to implement your three properties using the JavaFX property classes, and then register specific change listeners with each of them. Is there a reason not to use that approach?